# How to slice Numpy datetime64 array

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

I have a python zip with 2 arrays

zipped = zip(array1[], array2[])

Where array1 is of type numpy.datetime64[] adn array2 is a temperature

I want to make a time window in 1st array so i can have fixed array len (because i have other zipped arrays but they differ in array length)

this is what i have:

```
start = np.datetime64('2016-06-17T15:00')
stop = np.datetime64('2016-06-19T15:00')

index, temp = sensor_cal.get_arrays('ParsedData/parsed.csv')
print(index)
print(temp)
index2 = index[start:stop] /////////////This doesn't work
print(index2)
```

How can i define a time window like this....
My objective is to get same length arrays in the same time window (because they were previously frequency normalized) and then make a graph where xAxis is time and the various series correspond to the multiple temperature sensor arrays

My error:

> ['2016-06-17T13:23:59.000000000' '2016-06-17T13:24:59.000000000'  '2016-06-17T13:25:59.000000000' ..., '2016-06-20T09:55:59.000000000' 
>   '2016-06-20T09:56:59.000000000' '2016-06-20T09:57:59.000000000'] [[
>   nan]  [         nan]  [         nan]  ...,   [ 25.54      ]  [
>   25.56333333]  [ 25.59333333]] Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main_cal.py", line 10, in 
>       index[start:stop] IndexError: failed to coerce slice entry of type numpy.datetime64 to integer

Comment: In `index[start:stop]`, `start` and `stop` must be integers, indexes to positions in the array, e.g.  `index[2:5]`.  They are not values.  You may need to review what indexing and slicing does in `numpy` (or for that matter Python lists).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pandas` indexing which is designed for this. 'series' is a 1d array with an index attached. With reference to Wes McKinney's Python for Data Analysis:

```
import pandas as pd
temp = np.random.randn(366)
time_series = pd.Series(temp,index=np.arange(np.datetime64('2015-12-19'),np.datetime64('2016-12-19')))

start = np.datetime64('2016-01-17T15:00')
stop = np.datetime64('2016-06-19T15:00')
time_series[start:stop]
```

Output:

```
2016-01-18   -0.690170
2016-01-19   -0.638598
2016-01-20    0.231680
2016-01-21   -0.202787
2016-01-22   -1.333620
2016-01-23    1.525161
2016-01-24   -0.908140
2016-01-25    0.493663
2016-01-26   -1.768979
2016-01-27    0.147327
...
```