# Index/Slicing Pandas DataFrame with Numpy datetime64 objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, indexing

I'd like to be able to figure out if I can get the following to work (Pandas 0.23.4). Any help would be most appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 12
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01', periods=rows, freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(rows), index=rng)

print(df.loc['2011-01'])
print(df.loc[np.datetime64('2011-01')])
```

The first `print` does what I would expect: shows all the rows that are in Jan of 2011. However, the second one throws an `KeyError` because the value is not in the index. I was hoping that it would provide the same output, but after some testing I realize that it is looking for an exact match 2011-01-01, which is not in the DataFrame. I'd like for the second one to work, so that I can use `numpy.arange` or `pandas.date_range` to easily generate arrays of dates that I can loop through. Anyone got this to work?
(Seems like [this works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37969061/how-to-slice-numpy-datetime64-array), but only if you have an exact match for the dates.)

Comment: Thanks for the help cryptonome and jpp. Unfortunately, it seems like the answer for this particular version of Pandas is "No. You can't do this exactly." I marked jpp answer as correct, because it doesn't require another loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a function to convert `np.datetime64` to Pandas-compatible strings:

```
def stringify(x):
    year = x.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 1970
    month = x.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
    return f'{year}-{month:02}'

a = df.loc['2011-01']
b = df.loc[stringify(np.datetime64('2011-01'))]

assert a.equals(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

use [DatetimeIndex.to_period()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period) & [Period.month](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.month.html?highlight=period)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

rows = 12
rng = pd.date_range('2011-01', periods=rows, freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(rows), index=rng)

# print(df.loc['2011-01'])
for idx, di in enumerate(df.index.to_period()):
    if di.month == np.datetime64('2011-01').item().month:
        print(f'loc: [{idx}] == {df.index[idx]}')
```

output:

```
# loc: [0] == 2011-01-31 00:00:00
```

Since your df indexes consist of the end of the month dates, you can use this trick to use `df.loc` to get the row:

```
>>>> df.loc[df.index == np.datetime64('2011-03', 'D') -1]
            0
2011-02-28  1

>>>> df.loc[df.index == np.datetime64('2011-04', 'D') -1]
            0
2011-03-31  2

>>>> df[df.index == np.datetime64('2011-12', 'D') -1]
             0
2011-11-30  10

# use 2012 January 1st minus one day to get 2011 Dec 31st
>>>> df[df.index == np.datetime64('2012-01', 'D') -1]
             0
2011-12-31  11
```

Comment: Thanks @cryptonome. The to_period method is interesting; I'll have to consider that. However, I was hoping for a way to do this without adding another explicit loop, if possible. The implicit looping in Numpy/Pandas is much more efficient...

Comment: since your index is always the end of the month & your `np.datetime64` is in `year-month` format, there's a trick that you can use for that. let me edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks again, @cryptonome. Unfortunately, your new code only works for exact matches. I was hoping to do a search for the entire month.  I appreciate your help, though.

Comment: that's alright @Ryan, maybe i misunderstood your question